# How to make scatter plots of scalar fields with free software?

Tags: python, plotting

How can I make a scatter plot like the following, where the density of points represents the magnitude of the scalar field at that point. Consider for example the probability density for an atom:

[image: Example plot]

I managed to plot something like this as a color plot (see my question and the pictures here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113331/pcolormesh-in-polar-coordinates) but I didn't find any option to make such a scatter plot as above.

A requirement is that it should be done with free software for linux. Preferences:

- pgfplots or pstricks
- mathplotlib or another python library

I am interested in such types of plots in 2d as well as in 3d.

Answer (score 3):

Points for a scatterplot of a probability density function can simply be sampled 
from it. I used the `Psi(X1, X2)` you defined in your linked post.

The number of sample points, alpha and the marker type can be tuned. The axis can be renormalized to the dimensions of th meshgrid.

[image: Scatter plot of crossreferenced field]

In the code below I take the absolute value of the input matrix because it had negative values. You might want to set negative values to 0 instead and add a different colored scatterplot to the same axis if you have positive and negative data.

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
def sample(mat, count=10000):
    shape = mat.shape
    magn = np.abs(mat) # input should not be negative
    cumsum = magn.cumsum()

    samples = [None] * count
    for i, rand in enumerate(np.random.random(count) * magn.sum()):
        idx = np.argmax(cumsum > rand)
        samples[i] = (idx % shape[0], idx / shape[1])

    return samples

sample_x, sample_y = zip(*sample(psi(X1,X2)))
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(sample_x, sample_y, alpha=0.25, marker=".")
```